# Using QString as the key in std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, qt, c++17, stdhash

I'm trying to use `QString` as the key in a `std::unordered_map`, however I get the error:

> error C2280: 'std::hash<_Kty>::hash(const std::hash<_Kty> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

I can't switch to  `QHash` because the value-type of the map is non-copyable. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Put the `hash` implementation in a header, and make sure that you include that header everywhere the map is used.

A trivial implementation that forwards to `qHash` should be sufficient:

```
#include <QHash>
#include <QString>
#include <functional>

namespace std {
  template<> struct hash<QString> {
    std::size_t operator()(const QString& s) const noexcept {
      return (size_t) qHash(s);
    }
  };
}
```

Even though `std::size_t` is larger than `unsigned int` on common 64 bit platforms, and thus the hash doesn't change across its full length - this isn't a problem. The standard places no such requirement on an `std::hash` implementation.

---

Let's not forget, though, that modifying anything in the `std` namespace is generally undefined behavior and unnecessary.

**TL;DR:

You're allowed to specialize certain *type* and *variable* templates, and only if the specialization depends on at least one user-defined type. You can't fully specialize for built-in nor C++ library types.**

See [*Extending the namespace std*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) for reference. There, we read:

> It is undefined behavior to add declarations or definitions to namespace std or to any namespace nested within std, with a few exceptions noted below.

Mainly, it is allowed to specialize certain *types* in the `std` namespace:

> *It is allowed to add template specializations for any standard library class template to the namespace std* only if the declaration *depends on at least one program-defined type* and the specialization satisfies all requirements for the original template, except where such specializations are prohibited.

Note that what's legal is specializing **types**, i.e. classes. Functions and member functions? Not ever:

> It is undefined behavior to declare a full specialization of any standard library function template, [... or] member function of a standard library class template, [... or] member function template of a standard library class or class template.

Another limited exception is for variable templates:

> It is undefined behavior to declare a full or partial specialization of any standard library variable template, *except where explicitly allowed*.

Emphasis mine in all cases. As always, there are further [details that one should get acquainted with](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std).

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that there is no `std::hash<QString>()` specialization. It's easy enough to define your own with reasonably good performance based on the [dbj2](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) algorithm:

```
#include <QString>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<QString>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const QString& s) const noexcept
        {
            const QChar* str = s.data();
            std::size_t hash = 5381;

            for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
                hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + ((str->row() << 8) | (str++)->cell());

            return hash;
        }
    };
}
```

include that in files which use a `QString` in a `std::unordered_map` and the error goes away.

Comment: You can simplify that to `return std::hash<std::string>()(s.toStdString());`

Comment: @RSahu sure could, but it won't be as performant due to the unicode to utf8 conversion and the memory allocation.

Comment: Probably even `return qHash(s)`.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus, that is true.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, since QString can contain internal \0 characters.

Comment: @krojew thanks, didn't realize that. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Like said before, it's simpler just to return qHash value.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in newer versions of Qt, std::hash is defined for QString so you can use it with std::unordered_map directly. (It works with Qt 5.14 on my machine.)